# Is the "default" story in Mass Effect 3 a direct continuation of the "default" from Mass Effect 2?

Tags: mass-effect-3

If I start a new game in Mass Effect 3, without importing a save file, will the default story continue on with the same decisions that the default story of Mass Effect 2 had.

Obviously here I'm talking about the decisions that Mass Effect 2 made about Mass Effect 1 if you didn't continue on the save.

Things like whether Wrex is alive, or who died on Virmire, or whether or not the Rachni survived.

In Mass Effect 2 Wrex was dead, the opposite gender from yourself survived Virmire (Ashley for male Shep, Kaiden for female Shep) and (as far as I can tell) the Rachni were killed.

Obviously if I continue over a "default" Mass Effect 2 playthrough, then those decisions will also continue on (in addition to all of the Mass Effect 2 decisions I made) but if I start a new "default" Mass Effect 3 game, then will all those Mass Effect 1 decisions still be the same? Or will Wrex suddenly be alive etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the 'Default' load in ME3 is a continuation of the 'default' entry to ME2.